# Yii2- view file doesn't exist while rendering ('profile#parentVerticalTab3')

Tags: javascript, yii2

The view file does not exist: C:..\user\profile#parentVerticalTab3.php

I used this code to render

> return $this->render('profile#parentVerticalTab3');

Actually '#parentVerticalTab3' is a javascript code. I know this is a wrong way. Do anyone know how to solve this

Comment: what is your view filename?

Comment: actually view filename is 'profile'. I have a jquery tabs in that view file. So I want to select it by default using '#parentVerticalTab1', '#parentVerticalTab2'.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple pass a parameter and then accordingly set the tab selected in your view.

```
return $this->render('profile', ['tab' => 'parentVerticalTab3']);
```

Then in your view check:

```
if($tab == 'parentVerticalTab3')
{
     // Use jquery/PHP to select tab
}
```